# GCC missing braces around initializer with static module level variable

Tags: c, gcc

I'm getting the following warnings:

```
test.c:8:1: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
 static foo x = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
 ^
test.c:8:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘x.a’) [-Wmissing-braces]
```

I'm compiling with `gcc -Wall test.c`

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    float a[3];
}foo;

static foo x = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

int main()
{
    printf("%lf", x.a[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Am I initializing x incorrectly?

When I compile without -Wall, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

`static foo x ={ {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} };`

Outer Braces are for indicating initialization of `struct foo`.

Inner Braces are for indicating initialization of `array a`.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, your initialization shall look as following:

```
static foo x = {{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}};
```